# Python time module mktime method returns DST as set to 1 when it is not DST

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, utc, mktime

Running the following line returns a timestamp that is one hour head of the expected UTC

```
time.mktime(datetime.now().astimezone(pytz.UTC).timetuple())
```

Example:
  Date: 09/19/2017 15:19:56

Correct UTC: **1505834396**

Resulting UTC from line above: **1505837996**

How would I get the correct UTC timestamp without it being one hour ahead?

Comment: I confirm the behavior.  The hours seem to be one hour ahead!